# Running total from another field

Tags: running-totals

I have a table just like that:

```
date      sales    rest 
1/1/2017   52        0
2/1/2017   30        0
3/1/2017   10        200.
```

I only have the rest in the last date and i want to make it like this:

```
1/1/2017   52        240
2/1/2017   30        210
3/1/2017   10        200.
```

What I want to achieve to to calculate in a new column the rest for every date from the sum of the day's sales and the last days rest.

Can someone suggest a query ?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server & Postgres:

> ```
> WITH RN AS
> (
>     SELECT date, sales, rest,
>            COALESCE(LAG(sales) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC), 0) LG
>
>     FROM sales
> )
> SELECT   date, sales, 
>          SUM(LG + rest) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) rest
> FROM     RN
> ORDER BY date
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | sales | rest
> :--------- | ----: | ---:
> 2017-01-01 |    52 |  240
> 2017-01-02 |    30 |  210
> 2017-01-03 |    10 |  200
> ```

For MySql:

> ```
> SELECT date, sales, rest
> FROM (
>       SELECT t.date,
>              t.sales,
>              @acm := @acm + t.rest + @last_sales AS rest,
>              @last_sales := t.sales
>       FROM   sales t,
>              (SELECT @last_sales := 0, @acm := 0) r
>       ORDER BY t.date desc
>       ) X
> ORDER BY date;
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | sales | rest
> :--------- | ----: | ---:
> 2017-01-01 |    52 |  240
> 2017-01-02 |    30 |  210
> 2017-01-03 |    10 |  200
> ```

*SQL-Server dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2abceb0cafd2b96e43da077eb0e86a71)*

*MySQL dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=46c7669cf9ea38044334d42e76250743)*

*Postgres dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8dacb653983ec1feab2e5498b6406d35)*